# Selecting a single row using EF in MVC 3 vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to get back a single from from a EF database model using the below line of code..

```
Dim _classRoom As classrm = db.classrms.Select(Function(b) b.Course_ID = _CurrCourse.course_ref)
```

Where classrm is the name of the entity and db is declared as a new entity.  What I am trying to do is select a row from the entity based on matching Course_ID which in this model is a string. So that I can later use the variable _classRoom to get other items out of the same row.. However I am getting the following error:

```
   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Boolean]' to type 'Trial_Online.classrm'.
```

Anyone got any ideas??? I have to preform similar tasks with several different Entities but if I get pointed in the right direction I can manage from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Where` instead of `Select` to filter the results, and add `First()` or `Single()` to the end:

```
Dim _classRoom As classrm = db.classrms.Where(Function(b) b.Course_ID = _CurrCourse.course_ref).First()
```

The difference between `First()` and `Single()` is that `Single()` will throw an exception if there is more than 1 element in the result.  Both will throw an exception if the result sequence is empty.

You can also use `FirstOrDefault()` and `SingleOrDefault()` to return `Nothing` if there are no results.

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with query syntax in VB.NET, but in C# I'm pretty sure you have to add `First()` or `Single()` to the end of the query for it to project the result into an object instance. Otherwise I think you get a resultset (probably an `IQueryable` object).